# Double-struck zero and one

Tags: fonts, math-mode

I am trying to typeset double-struck digits in math mode. They have to come from the same font.

I tried

```
\mathbbm{0}
```

from the bbm package and

```
\mathds{0}
```

from the dsfont package.

The document compiles OK, but the characters do not show up. Interestingly, the versions for 1 do work.

The minimal examples are:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dsfont}
% or: \usepackage{bbm} with mathbbm below
\begin{document}
$\mathds{0}$  % doesn't print
$\mathds{1}$  % prints
\end{document}
```

The log file has error messages of the kind:

```
Missing character: There is no 0 in font bbm10!
```

I guess that's the problem, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. In particular, it is important to see which packages and fonts you are loading. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Did you happen to notice messages such as `Missing character: There is no 0 in font bbm10!` and `Missing character: There is no 0 in font dsrom10!` in the log file?

Comment: @darthbith I have added the MWE.

Comment: @Mico Thanks, I have added output from the log file.

Comment: @ziutek - So there you have it: the `dsfont` and `\bbm` packages simply don't provide a double-struck (aka blackboard bold) `0`. I suggest you peruse the documentation of the [mathalfa](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathalfa) package to choose a font package that does feature a double-struck `0` -- and `1`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to @Mico, I found the following solution.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bb=boondox]{mathalfa}
\begin{document}
$\mathbb{0}$ $\mathbb{1}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I think the most elegant version (since it does not overwrite \mathbb) is the following:

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mymathbb}{U}{BOONDOX-ds}{m}{n}
\begin{document}
    $\mymathbb{0}$ \\
    $\mymathbb{1}$
\end{document}
```

see [Use both boondox-ds and the blackboard fonts from amsfonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215822/use-both-boondox-ds-and-the-blackboard-fonts-from-amsfonts)

Comment: Btw, use `\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mymathbb}{U}{bbold}{m}{n}` to use the _bbold_ font instead of _boondox_

Comment: _bbold_ is serif while _boondox_ is sans-serif.

Answer (score 3):

```
\usepackage{bbold}

\begin{document}
$\mathbb{0}$ \\
$\mathbb{1}$
\end{document}
```

This also works. It's not the same font as used in the `mathalfa` package, but it also produces double struck 0s and 1s.