# Use both boondox-ds and the blackboard fonts from amsfonts

Tags: fonts, math-mode, blackboard

I want to use the blackboard bold font `boondox-ds` provided by the `boondox` package, but keep, for denoting number sets, the `\mathbb` from `amsfonts`. What `boondox-ds` does, however, is overwriting `\mathbb`. How can I, instead, import `boondox-ds` to, say, `\mathbbbondox`?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Note that there is no default `\mathbb`. I've edited your question according to my best guess at your meaning. If I've misunderstood, please roll back my changes and clarify it yourself.

Comment: Two blackboard bold fonts not very different from each other will confuse readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you can spare a maths alphabet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,amsfonts}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbx}{U}{BOONDOX-ds}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbx}{bold}{U}{BOONDOX-ds}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbbx} {U}{BOONDOX-ds}{b}{n}
\begin{document}

\verb|\mathbb|
  \[
    \mathbb{N Z R}
  \]

\verb|\mathbx|
  \[
    \mathbx{N Z R}
  \]

\end{document}
```

[image: Variant blackboard fonts]

Comment: Thanks, works perfektly! But I can use anything insetead of `\mathbx`, right? Because at first your comment "Provided you can spare a maths alphabet:" made me think I `mathbx` was also defined by `amsfonts`

Comment: @黄雨伞 Yes. You can use anything. Just you only have 16 maths fonts. So it is possible to run out.