# Blackboard Bold i

Tags: math-mode, symbols, packages, amsmath, mathbb

Although it is not standard notation, I quite like the fact that in Mathematica, a blackboard bold `i` is used to represent the imaginary unit. Apart from making it stick out, it allows me to write things such as

[image],

allowing me to use the variable 'i' as an iterator in series, etc. To achieve this in LaTeX, I've made use of the `bbm` package (`\mathbbm i`), however this doesn't render as nicely as the standard AMS math `\mathbb` command, in fact, it looks pixellated up close:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve a nicer blackboard bold `i` symbol? I'm not very fond of what is offered by the packages `bbold`, `mathbbol` or `dsfont` packages either, I want to get something as close to AMS's `\mathbb` as possible.

Comment: Maybe better privide a MWE?

Comment: I don't think it's anything to do with my compiler, it's just simply the way the `bbm` package is defined. In fact if you zoom into any of the symbols in the package documentation, you'll notice they pixelate too: http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/bbm/bbm.pdf

Comment: Well, if you use a bitmap font you have to expect some pixels. You won't get them with a scalable font.

Comment: Is there a non-bitmap font alternative?

Comment: Are you free to use LuaLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX?

Comment: I did not refer to your compiler - rather to the used font related stuff.

Comment: Opinion - based comment: This blackboard i letter looks ugly in this context!

Comment: No, *please*, no! Blackboard bold for the imaginary unit is even worse than typesetting it upright! `;-)`

Comment: @egreg Do you propose an alternative which lets me still use `i` as an index?

Comment: @LukeCollins Start indexing from k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I use dafrick's answer at [Double-struck zero and one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204998/double-struck-zero-and-one/399950#399950) to use the boondox-ds versions of bb fonts, designated here as `\mymathbb{}`.  I used `j` in one location so that you can see it is not pixelated.

The fonts are installed via the `boondox-dx` package, which is not invoked below, so as not to overwrite the native `\mathbb` implementation otherwise available through `amssymb`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mymathbb}{U}{BOONDOX-ds}{m}{n}
\begin{document}
    \[
      x_i(t) = \mathop{\mathrm{Re}}(A_i e^{8000\pi\mymathbb{j}t}c^{\phi_i\mymathbb{i}}) \text{for $i = 1, 2, 3$}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**FOLLOW UP**

In comments, the OP asks for the `\mathbb{i}` from TG Pagella Math (OpenType format), but for use in `pdflatex`, which is not available.  Since it is only a single glyph that is being requested, here is a kludge to obtain it:

Create the document TGbbi.tex as follows, and compile in Xelatex:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\begin{document}
$\mathbb{i}$
\end{document}
```

It creates the output TGbbi.pdf containing only the Pagella version of `\mathbb{i}`.  Now, reverting back to `pdflatex`, we are going to call upon that graphic for use in a macro named `\bbi` defined as

```
\newcommand\bbi{\ThisStyle{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle\mathbb{i}$}\includegraphics[height=\ht0]{TGbbi}}}
```

This macro requires the `graphicx` package (to import the graphic) and the `scalerel` package (to auto-scale it to the proper math size, taken as the vertical height of the regular `\mathbb{i}`).  Thus, the implementation (showing use in several different math sizes) is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,scalerel,graphicx}
\newcommand\bbi{\ThisStyle{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle\mathbb{i}$}\includegraphics[height=\ht0]{TGbbi}}}
\begin{document}
    \[
      x_i(t) = \mathop{\bbi\mathrm{Re}}(A_i e^{8000\pi\bbi t}c^{\phi_i\bbi}) \text{for $i = 1, 2, 3$}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Zoom:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm interested in using the  Tex Gyre Pagella font family as shown in @Mico's answer, however I can't find the relevant family name. I always have trouble finding these out. Any ideas?

Comment: @LukeCollins At http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/texgyrepagella/, it says "The TeX Gyre Pagella family of fonts is based on the URW Palladio family, but heavily extended. **Math support is available in OpenType format**." (emphasis added).  I understand this to mean that  to get math support like `\mathbb` using that font, one must use `xelatex` or `lualatex` and not `pdflatex`.  But I will try to examine this further and post another comment if I find otherwise.

Comment: @LukeCollins See my **FOLLOW UP** for a way to fake it.

Answer (score 5):

If you're free to use LuaLaTeX and the `unicode-math` package and its `\setmathfont` macro, there are quite a few math fonts to choose from that provide a "double-struck" lowercase-i character.

Hopefully, one of the following eight choices will appeal to you. :-)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Stix Two Text} % choose the text font...

% Setting up eight [8!] math fonts
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[version=lm]
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}[version=cambria]
\setmathfont{Asana Math}[version=asana]
\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}[version=stix2]
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[version=xits]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}[version=termes]       
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}[version=pagella]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}[version=dejavu]

\newcommand\blurb{$\mathbb{123}\quad\mathbb{hij}\quad e^{\phi_i\mathbb{i}}$}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Latin Modern & \mathversion{lm}      \blurb\\
Cambria      & \mathversion{cambria} \blurb\\
Asana        & \mathversion{asana}   \blurb\\[1ex]
Stix Two     & \mathversion{stix2}   \blurb\\
XITS         & \mathversion{xits}    \blurb\\[1ex]
Termes       & \mathversion{termes}  \blurb\\
Pagella      & \mathversion{pagella} \blurb\\
DejaVu       & \mathversion{dejavu}  \blurb
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 as usual. Why do you need luatex here? Isn't lmodern a standard package for pdftex?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner - Thanks. The OpenType version of Latin Modern Math has many more glyphs than does the "standard" version, i.e., the one that's loaded via `\usepackage{lmodern}`. The seven other math fonts used in the answer also feature lots and lots of glyphs.

Comment: HI Mico, thanks for your answer. Can this be achieved in pdfLaTeX using a similar strategy to @Steven B. Segletes' answer? I particularly like how the double stroke i looks in TeX Gyre Pagella.

Comment: @LukeCollins - There's a reason I started my answer with "If you're free to use LuaLaTeX...". To quote from the TeXGyre website: "TeX-Gyre-Math is a col­lec­tion of maths fonts to match the text fonts of the TeX-Gyre col­lec­tion. The col­lec­tion is available in OpenType for­mat, only;". Thus, I don't think it's possible to replicate the look of the "Pagella" line in the answer using methods available in pdfLaTeX. Aside: Is something stopping you from using LuaLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX?

Comment: @Mico No not really, I'm just used to pressing F5 in TeXStudio :) Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @LukeCollins - TeXStudio lets you customize what is run when`F5`is pressed. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The package [cmathbb](https://ctan.org/pkg/cmathbb) offers Blackboard Bold characters compatible with the Computer Modern.

It is the only package that I found to provide good results for \mathbb{i} for pdflatex.

Comment: +1 Nice new package, though I'd describe it more as outline font than a blackboard bold.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!