# Problem with \mathbb

Tags: mathbb

Here is the Latex:

```
 % !TeX spellcheck = en_US
\documentclass[11 pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{fouriernc} % Use this 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{  amsthm, amssymb,latexsym,amsfonts}

\usepackage[reqno,fleqn]{amsmath}


\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\mathbb{Var}\left(X_n \right) = \mathbb{E} \left( \mathbb{Var}\left(X_n| X_{n-1} \right) \right) +
\mathbb{Var}\left( \mathbb{E}\left(X_n| X_{n-1} \right)  \right) . 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

And here what I get:
[image]

Any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: There is no lower case letters for `mathbb`.

Comment: See e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/400364) for getting lower-case double-stroke letters.

Comment: From the link above the solution https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/400371/ also works with XeLaTeX (and not just LuaLaTeX as is sort of implied). MWE: `\documentclass[11 pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[reqno,fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\begin{document}
$\mathbb{Var}$
\end{document}`

Comment: Marijn, This does not work for me.

Comment: Why not? Do you get an error message? Which one? Maybe you don't have this specific font installed, but there are others, see the list in the answer that I linked.

Comment: @Marijn, I have a lot of error messages. I gave up and use \DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{\mathbb{V}ar}.

Comment: In LaTeX the first error message is usually the most important, any further problems are often caused by the first problem and may be solved once the first error is addressed. Also, with an MWE of eight lines as in my comment it is unlikely to get a lot of errors, because there is not a lot of code to cause errors :) so if you want you can post the first error when you try the MWE and we can see if there is an easy solution.

Comment: @Marijn . O'k. Here what I got:"Undefined control sequence. \file_get:nnN".

Comment: There was a bug related to  `unicode-math` that caused this problem some time ago. It is usually fixed by updating to the most recent versions of packages. If you use MikTeX then you should update in the Package Manager in normal mode and again in admin mode. If you use TeX Live then you can update in the terminal using `tlmgr update --all`.

Comment: @ Marijn, Should I update unicode-math only?

Comment: Best to update everything, packages are interdependent so the most recent version of one package may depend on a recent version of another package.

Comment: I installed unicode-math and I have got the following error: "Package filehook Error: Detected unknown definition of \InputIfFileExists. ... option of 'filehook' to overwrite it.}{}".

Comment: That is a known problem in the `filehook` package (see https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/filehook/issues/1/latex-will-change-definition-of), a fix was released on February 4. Did you update that package too (and all other packages that you have, just to avoid further bugs)?

Comment: After installing unocode-math package in Admin mode I see: "File `unicode-math.sty' not found. \setmathfont". I giva up. :-)